# Java - for each cycle typing

Tags: java, list, inheritance, foreach

**My question:** How to get following code to work?

**Code:** `for (CustomTab tab : tabPane.getTabs()) { ... }`

Or what method to write in potentially created class customTabPane to get it in compatible object type. I read something about `extends` in generics - example: `ObservableList<? extends something>`.

Comment: If `tabPane.getTabs()` retuns either `CustomTab[]` or something that implements `Iterable<CustomTab>`, the code will work.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you're talking about two different things I think. First the for each loop. You can use it for any type that implements `Iterable` e.g.:

```
class CustomTab {};

class TabPane<T> implements Iterable<T> {

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        ...
    }
}

public void main() {
    TabPane pane = new TabPane<CustomTab>();
    for (CustomTab i : pane) {
       ... 
    }
}
```

The second topic is generics. You can restrict the TabPane to be defined only for a inheritance tree. For example if you want TabPane to be constructed for CustomTab and derived types you can code it like that:

```
class TabPane<T extends CustomTab> implements Iterable<T> {

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        ...
    }
}
```

So this will be valid:

```
class DerivedPane extends CustomTab{};
new TabPane<DerivedPane>();
```

But this won't:

```
class OtherPane{};
new TabPane<OtherPane>();
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand you. I am learning Java only for one year ... I want somehow override method getTabs in TabPane from JavaFX for return type `ObservableList<CustomTab>`, but that method is final and is returning `ObservableList<Tab>`. How to do it by relative way?

Comment: Ok so this is a complete different question... As you mentioned this method is final so you can't override it and you rather don't want to do it. I don't really know why you want the foreach construct here... You can alway do sth like that `for (Tab tab: tabPane.getTabs()) { if (tab instanceof CustomTab) { /* your code here*/ }}`.

Comment: Sorry, but you don't understand me. How to access to CustomTab methods in loop for each with other way than: `for (Tab tab : tabPane.getTabs()) {
    ((CustomTab) tab).stopFlash();
}` I think that retype isn't necessary and I think that others programmers are doing it differently.

Comment: I think I understand you, but I do really think it is the best way as long as you use the JavaFX API, you can always write a wrapper around the TabPane, but I really think It would be much worse and you would have to do the cast anyway...

Comment: This question may be very funny, but I'm thinking about it a lot. When is called constructor of CustomTab if I retype to it from Tab? When I tried to write this piece of code `System.out.println("some text");` to CustomTab constructor, it never print anything during retype from Tab to CustomTab. But how can I access to CustomTab uninitialized object and call their methods? I'm confused about that a lot ...

Comment: During the casting no new objects are created. You just say: "treat the object as this type". The object is created once, when calling `new` operator.

Comment: Anyway you should get back to some basis ;).

Comment: I know that constructor of some class is called when is created some instance, but logically; when I retype Tab to CustomTab which adds some functions and in CustomTab constructor are initialized some objects which are used in other methods which I call on retyped Tab so where these objects are initialized?

Comment: The casting, you call retyping, does not add any methods. It just claims that this object is of that type, so you can use its methods.  Please read some book about java.

Comment: Tomorrow I will start with reading; don't worry about that. :-) But I still don't understand how it all is synchronized between itself.